# Can we get rid of the "support" tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

It seems like it's way too general and is probably misused.

Comment: I agree, it's a useless tag!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's pretty much the definition of a meta-tag. With only five questions  attached a few minutes ago, it's a no-brainer.

The attached questions have been edited, the tag will be purged within 24h.